# How to sync a Dropbox folder with a local folder using Dropbox API v2

Tags: java, android, dropbox-api

I could not find an official API to do this.
Does this mean I would have to implement this functionality from scratch?

Comment: The Dropbox API offers calls for uploading, downloading, listing files, etc. but it doesn't offer a pre-built syncing logic, so you would need to implement whatever sort of syncing you need in your app.

Comment: Any suggestions or guidelines on how to do that?

Comment: You could probably write a service that periodically checks files/timestamps and syncs them if necessary

Comment: I'm afraid Dropbox doesn't have any official resources for this. Perhaps someone here can recommend a third party guide though.